# How do I use Perl to print to a text file?

Tags: linux, perl

I tried to create a word list starting with 0500000000 to 0600000000 with Perl code

```
#!/bin/perl -w
$k = 10;
$width = 10;
for $i ( 500000000 .. 600000000 ) {
    printf "%${width}.${k}ld\n", $i;
}
```

I need to print the result to a text file.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you really want a file with 100 million + 1 consecutive numbers in it?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ perl -e 'print "$_\n" for "0500000000" .. "0600000000"' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Using filehandles.  For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie qw(:all);

open my $FILE, '>', 'filename.txt';

my $k = 10;
my $width = 10;
for $i ( 500000000 .. 600000000 ) {
    printf {$FILE} "%${width}.${k}ld\n", $i;
}

close $FILE;
```

Use file mode `>` to truncate any existing file, or `>>` to append to it.

Comment: That's old style. Use open with three arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use STDOUT redirection?

```
# perl yourscript.pl > yourfile.txt
```

Comment: I think you meant STDOUT redirection and not "pipe".

Answer (score 1):

To print to a text file, read up on [PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html).  This will tell you how to open a handle to a file, print to that file, and close the handle when you are done.